# How Can I Use Data Annotations Attribute Classes to Fail Empty Strings in Forms?

Tags: c#, forms, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I was trying to require a text input field in a form, which implies that there needs to be something in the form. However, adding a `[Required]` tag to my model wasn't working. Specifically, look at the User Name property:

```
public class ColumnWidthMetaData {
    [DisplayName("Column Name")]
    [Required]
    public string ColName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Primary Key")]
    public int pKey { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Column Width")]
    [Required]
    public int Width { get; set; }
}
```

This allows empty strings to get past model validation and eventually a database error is thrown when it attempts to insert a NULL value for User Name.

How can I change these attributes so they do what they seem like they should do?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

After a lot of Googling and looking on Stackoverflow, I had nothing.

I went to MSDN and looked at the [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

There I looked more closely at the `Required` attribute, and noticed the [`AllowEmptyStrings` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.allowemptystrings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Setting this to `false` tells the attribute not to allow any empty strings. In at least some versions this is the default behavior, which makes sense seeing as how the point of `Required` is to require that something be entered, and an empty string indicates that nothing was entered. You may not need to add this, if it's the default, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit.

This doesn't solve the problem though, as by default empty strings are coerced to `null`, which is not an empty string, and is therefore allowed. This seems absurd, as `Required` is supposed to test if something was entered, and `null` indicates nothing was entered. However, the `AllowEmptyStrings` page has a link to `DisplayFormAttribute`'s Property [`ConvertEmptyStringsToNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.convertemptystringtonull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you set this to `false`, then empty strings will remain empty strings, and then the required tag will not allow them.

So, here's the fix:

```
public class ColumnWidthMetaData {
    [DisplayName("Column Name")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull=false)]
    public string ColName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Primary Key")]
    public int pKey { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull=false)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Column Width")]
    [Required]
    public int Width { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I checking  Assembly System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll, v4.0.0.0 and I see following comment: public bool AllowEmptyStrings { get; set; } // Returns: // true if an empty string is allowed; otherwise, false. The default value is  false. - So where is a problem? Default value is false.

Comment: @qub1n ditto Assembly System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0

Comment: Just to note that the default value of `AllowEmptyStrings` is `false` (in .NET Core 6 at least) so you don't need to specify it.

Comment: This was a long time ago. I'm sure things have changed in nearly 10 years, with multiple updated versions. In any case, specifying AllowEmptyStrings as false may not be required but it doesn't hurt to be explicit. It's also not the main point of the answer. The important bit is ConvertEmptyStringToNull.

Comment: An empty string IS a value. null is usually used to mean "There is no value".

Comment: @DrFloyd5 Yes, that's true. What's your point?

Answer (score 10):

I'd implement a new validation attribute like this and apply it to my model.

```
public class RequiredNotEmptyAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if(value is string) return !String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value);

        return base.IsValid(value);
    }
}
```

This will only work on the server side (client side will still only check for null).

Comment: return !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value) ?

Comment: see @peteski comment. -1. Will upvote when its fixed.

Comment: @petski fixed logic

Answer (score 6):

You could use `[MinLength(1)]`.  See [msdn docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.minlengthattribute?view=netframework-4.8).