# Required variable Rest

Tags: c#, json, rest

I want to do a request with [POST] and if some field it's null i don't follow to the Service. I want to stop the flow in the Controller. problem is with ModelState.IsValid it returns a true when it should be false and return a BadRequest

This is the code:

Model:

```
public class IdentityBrokerSettingsDetails
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Tenant { get; set; }

        // With interrogation mark you make it nullable
        [Required]
        public bool? Account { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool? StatusUserLogin { get; set; }

        public IdentityBrokerSettingsDetails(string tenant, bool? account, bool? statusUserLogin)
        {
            Tenant = tenant;
            Account = account;
            StatusUserLogin = statusUserLogin;
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PostIdentitySettingsDetails([FromBody] IdentityBrokerSettingsDetails identityBrokerSettingsDetails)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) //doesn't work
                return BadRequest();

        }
```

Image what is happening:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint, and show us a sample output from `identityBrokerSettingsDetails`?

Comment: i can't add picture, but I can describe: If I do a Post with Tennant and not tenant (tenant is that program is waiting) Tenant in IdentityBrokerSettingsDetails is null but ModelState.IsValid return is true. I don't understand why

Comment: Add the picture link (ie. `Image of this happening: http://image.url.here`), and I can convert it to an image.

Comment: @FrankerZ now you can see the image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ModelState.IsValid even when it should not be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923622/modelstate-isvalid-even-when-it-should-not-be)

Comment: Maybe this solution will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23939901/8300328

Answer (score 0):

For the string Tenant, you can use the following:
 `[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull=false)]`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.convertemptystringtonull?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Also, you can check

```
if (identityBrokerSettingsDetails == null || !Model.IsValid)
{ // Bad request code here
}
```

Comment: This not found because i can fill all fields less one and my IdentityBrokerSettingsDetails create a object. I want check if one is null or for example "" ModelState.IsInvalid return a false