# Missing input validation style in model binding

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-5, razor-pages

I have a simple Razor page view with the following form fields:

```
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" autocomplete="first-name">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" class="invalid-feedback" style="display:block"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label asp-for="Input.LastName" class="form-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="Input.LastName" class="form-control" autocomplete="last-name">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Input.LastName" class="invalid-feedback" style="display:block"></span>
                            </div>
```

and the following model:

```
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "First name")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Unfortunalely, when I send the form with empty values, despite of the error messages, inputs are still green:
[image]

I can add `required` tag to the form, but I would like control it by the jQuery validation, because I am going to add more advanced validations in the future.

Any ideas how to make the field like the following when the data does not met validation requirements?

`<input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" autocomplete="first-name" required>>`
[image]

Comment: What is the field style you are using?Can you share it?

Comment: I use this template: https://cartzilla.createx.studio/account-signin.html

Answer (score 0):

a quick answer would be this : `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)]`
but, you can also check this [Do not allow empty strings -DataAnnotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939738/how-can-i-use-data-annotations-attribute-classes-to-fail-empty-strings-in-forms) your questions is answered here with more info.

Comment: This is not correct answer. I've added this and the next validation rule like the following `[MinLength(2)]` and the value "A" validation error is "The field First name must be a string or array type with a minimum length of '2'." but the field style is still green